# AWS Step function task token sendTaskSuccess cross region

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I have case where the task token is received as an input from [Account A Region A] to the lambda deployed in [Account B Region B]. When sending the `sendTaskSuccess/sendTaskFailure`, should the lambda in Account B create [sfnClient](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/sfn/SfnClient.html) with Region A for this to work?

Are the task tokens region specific?

The problem is we only receive the task token as an input in Account B (no info about the region).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Task tokens are region specific. I validated this by deploying the sample code. The Sfn client has to be configured to the same AWS region as that of the state machine. If its in a different region, you will get this error message `ERROR   Invalid Token: 'Invalid token'`